# Creating home folders using Quest Active Roles cmdlets

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have created the following script to take data from a csv and create new users in AD:

```
Import-Csv c:\newusers.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {New-QADUser -name $_.'un' -ParentContainer 'CN=users,DC=domain,DC=local' -SamAccountName $_.'un' -FirstName $_.'fn' -LastName $_.'ln' -description '6' -userprincipalname $_.'un'  -UserPassword 'P@ssword' | Enable-QADUser | Set-QADUser -HomeDirectory '\\srv1\home\$_.un' -HomeDrive 'H:' -UserMustChangePassword $true | new-item c:\home\$_.un -type directory}
```

Everything seems to be working except for the new-item creation of the home folders. The `-homedirectory` and `-homedrive` commands work and they are named and mapped properly in the users profile but when I try to create the actual folders on the drive it creates a folder called `$_.un` and then throws errors for object already exists.

I have tried `c:\home\$_.un`, `c:\home\$_.'un'`, `c:\home\'$_.un` all with similar results. Can anyone shed some light on what is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this issue by adding `$un` variable like this:

```
Import-Csv c:\newusers.csv | ForEach-Object -Process {**$un=$_.un**; New-QADUser -name $.'un' -ParentContainer 'CN=users,DC=domain,DC=local' -SamAccountName $.'un' -FirstName $.'fn' -LastName $.'ln' -description '6' -userprincipalname $.'un'  -UserPassword 'P@ssword' | Enable-QADUser | Set-QADUser -HomeDirectory '\srv1\home\$.un' -HomeDrive 'H:' -UserMustChangePassword $true | new-item **c:\home\$un** -type directory}
```